# Async Job queue creator which works one job at the time

Tags: javascript, class, asynchronous, promise

I need to write a JavaScript module that exports a function `createJobQueue`, which creates an asynchronous job queue.

This job queue should have 3 methods:

- addJob
- cancelJob
- processAllJob

`addJob` adds a job to the end of the queue. It should return a promise that resolves with the value returned by job, whenever job ends up getting executed. (But `addJob` itself should not trigger execution of any jobs.) If job throws an error, then the promise returned by `addJob` should be rejected.

`cancelJob` removes a job from the queue. This should reject the promise returned by `addJob`. If no matching job is found, it does nothing.

When `processAllJobs` is called, the queue should process jobs (by invoking them) **one-at-a-time** in FIFO order until there are none left, then resolve with the number of jobs successfully processed (i.e., that did not reject or throw an error).

If any job cannot be processed (because job rejects or throws an error when invoked) the promise returned by `addJob` should be rejected. However, this should not stop `processAllJobs` from processing the rest of the queue.

**What I tried so far**

`addJob` is working good but I can't make `cancelJob` to reject job added by addJob and I can't make `proccessAllJobs` work **one-at-a-time**.

Here's the code:

```
function createJobQueue() {
     return new class jobQueue{
         constructor() {
             this.jobs = [];
         }
         
         addJob(job) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if (job()) {
                    this.jobs.push(job);
                    //console.log(this.jobs)
                    resolve(job());
                }
                throw new Error;
                reject();
            }) 
         }
         
         cancelJob(job) {
             return new Promise(resolve => {
                const index = this.jobs.findIndex(j => j === job);
                if (index === -1) {
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    this.jobs = this.jobs.filter((job, i) => i !== index);
                }
             })
         }
         
         processAllJobs() {            
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                let count = 0;
                
                this.jobs.forEach((f, index) => {
                    if(index === this.jobs.length-1) {
                        f()
                        .then(() => {
                            ++count
                        })
                        .catch((e) => {
                            resolve(count);
                        })
                    }
                    
                    //console.log("count", count);
                    f()
                    .then(() => {
                        count++
                    })
                    .catch()
                })
                    
                resolve(count);
            });                
         }
         
         getJobs() {
             console.log(this.jobs, "Next only jobs")
             console.log(this.jobs.forEach(f => f().then(console.log)));
         }
     }
}

const queue = createJobQueue();

queue.addJob(function() {
    return Promise.resolve("One")
});

queue.addJob(function() {
    return Promise.resolve("Two")
});

queue.addJob(function() {
    return Promise.resolve("Three")
});

//queue.getJobs();
console.log(queue.processAllJobs());

module.exports = { createJobQueue };
```

Comment: What should happen if `processAllJobs()` is called multiple times?

Comment: What should happen if `addJob` is called multiple times with the same job? And how would `cancelJob` interact with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation of `addJobs` goes against the requirements: it *does* execute the job, while it shouldn't. Realise that the promise constructor callback is executed immediately (synchronously).

Secondly, the trouble you have in sequencing the job execution can be more easily avoided by using `async`/`await`.

I would also suggest creating the job queue as a `Map` keyed by job: that way you can easily find an entry by a given job.

Finally, as you need to be able to resolve/reject a job's promise at some later time, when `processAllJobs` is called, you will need a reference to the appropriate resolve/reject functions. You could store those in the job queue: one pair per job.

Here is how it could look:

```js
class JobQueue{
    constructor() {
        this.jobs = new Map; // so we can key by job.
    }
     
    addJob(job) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
            this.jobs.set(job, {resolve, reject})
        );
    }
     
    cancelJob(job) {
        let deferred = this.jobs.get(job);
        if (this.jobs.delete(job)) deferred.reject("job cancelled");
    }
     
     async processAllJobs() {            
        let count = 0;

        for (let [job, {resolve, reject}] of this.jobs) {
            try {
                resolve(await job());
                count++;
            } catch(e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}

function createJobQueue() {
    return new JobQueue;
}

// Demo
const queue = createJobQueue();

// Instead of Promise.resolve, use a bit more flexible
//   promise-generation function:
const delay = (ms, value, err) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (err) reject(err); else resolve(value);
        console.log(err || value);
    }, ms)
);

queue.addJob(() => delay(500, "One"));
queue.addJob(() => delay(500, "Two"));
// add an example of a rejecting promise:
queue.addJob(() => delay(500, null, "Failing job"));
queue.addJob(() => delay(500, "Three"));


queue.processAllJobs().then(count =>
    console.log("count:", count)
);
```

Comment: I would suggest to simplify and only store the `resolve` function in the map. Then, in `cancelJob` do `resolve(new Promise.reject(new Error('Cancelled')))`, and in `processAllJobs` do `const promise = job(); resolve(promise); await promise.catch(ignore);`. This also ensures that when processing of a job has started you cannot cancel it any more.

Comment: That looks very great! But I can't understand only one part, how can I resolve the result of a job in the promise of the addJob

Comment: Then pass `await job()` as argument to `resolve`. See update.